# Regular concrete as a floor leveler?

Tags: concrete, floor

I have a small bathroom (6' x 7') that I want to lay tiles in. I'm on the ground floor of a 40 year old condo, so the floor is concrete. There's about 1/4" difference in height between the low and high points. I would like to use Quickcrete PSI 6000 (mixed to the thinnest consistency recommended) to level the floor. Will that work? I would go buy proper SLC, but I don't have a vehicle so getting home with 50lbs of mix will be difficult.

There's still some glue and other residue from the old linoleum floor left in the low spots. Will that affect the finish?

Comment: Quickrete has gravel in it, totally unsuitable for a resurfacing job like that.

Comment: 1/4" over 6' is no more than a typical slab might have. Can anyone who's not aware of it detect it by walking feel? I suspect that it's not an actual problem. Be sure it's not a faulty level bubble by flipping it end-for-end and checking again.

Answer (score 4):

Concrete is a terrible floor leveller, as it doesn't really bond well to anything other than itself, plus most commercial Quikcrete products have 3/8" aggregate in it (won't work for a 1/4" gap).

You don't need it anyhow: just use a good quality polymer modified tile mortar like Ceraflex 610 or Flextile 52 and install the tile.  You can easily use the mortar to float the tiles on a deeper or thinner bed.

If you can't get 50lbs of self leveller home without a vehicle, how will you get Quikcrete or mortar home?  It's all in 50lb bags.

Comment: +1 Yes the tile can be double buttered, thinset on the floor as usual and thinset on the tile to build it up. Larger the tile, the easier and cleaner the build up. Small tile will allow the grout to push through the tile joints easier. or just use a bag of thinset to float out the floor, all modified of course.